# System.SObjectException: Invalid field Category for Case

Tags: apex, class

Class.BatchCarrierUpdate.execute: line 59, column 1

```
            Boolean toUpdate = false;
            for(String strFieldName : caseToCarrierUpdatedFieldMap.keySet()){
                System.debug('****** CaseNumber: '+c.CaseNumber+'Case field: '+strFieldName+'  Value: '+c.get(strFieldName));
                System.debug('****** CaseNumber: '+c.CaseNumber+'CUD field: '+ caseToCarrierUpdatedFieldMap.get(strFieldName).CarrierUpdateField__c +'  Value: '+cud.get(caseToCarrierUpdatedFieldMap.get(strFieldName).CarrierUpdateField__c));
                if(c.get(strFieldName) != cud.get(caseToCarrierUpdatedFieldMap.get(strFieldName).CarrierUpdateField__c)){
                    c.put(strFieldName,cud.get(caseToCarrierUpdatedFieldMap.get(strFieldName).CarrierUpdateField__c));
                    toUpdate = true;
                }
            }

            if(toUpdate){
                casesToUpdate.add(c);
            }
```

Somewhere amongst this code is something creating an error, line 59 which is where the first sysem.debug starts.

Comment: Check `caseToCarrierUpdatedFieldMap`, if it contains `category`

Comment: My custom settings have all of the required fields there, that's why I'm scratching my head a bit

Comment: There is no field named as `category` on case. Do you mean to put `Category__c`

Comment: That's the reason for the error but I don't see where you see this mistake.

Comment: On line 5 and 6, you tryin to access and put values in case using c.get put for the fields that does not exists

Comment: Ah, I see now, thank you; so the workaround would be to add the fields to the Case object?

Comment: Am not sure, you need to ask the BA for this , shall that field be copied or was accidently added to `caseToCarrierUpdatedFieldMap`